# set_markersize not working for right side axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, axes, twinx

I'm messing around with some plot styles and ran into a curiosity. I have a plot with `twinx()` to produce ticks on the right-hand side as well as the left. I want to stagger some ticks, some going farther out that others.

I can add padding to any tick on any axes and push out the text via `ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].set_pad()`, but when I try to lengthen the tick via `ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick1line.set_markersize()`, it works for all axes EXCEPT the right side. Any insight?

Please see the code below. I've tried switching up the axis (ax1, ax2) and index.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,5)
x = np.exp(-t)*np.sin(2*t)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(t, x, alpha=0.0)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(t, x, alpha=1.0)

ax1.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax1.set_yticks([0.1, 0.2])
ax2.set_yticks([0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
ax2.set_xticks([1,2,3])

ax1.grid(True, color='lightgray')
ax2.grid(True, color='lightgray')

for a in [ax1, ax2]:
    a.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    a.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    a.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    a.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)

ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax2.set_axisbelow(True)

ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].set_pad(15)  #
ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick1line.set_markersize(15)

ax1.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].set_pad(15)  #
ax1.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick1line.set_markersize(15)

ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].set_pad(15)  #
ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick1line.set_markersize(15)

plt.savefig('fig.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `tick2line` instead of `tick1line`, since that's the one referring to the top/right axis, [according to the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/_modules/matplotlib/axis.html).

Change `ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick1line.set_markersize(15)` for:

```
ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].tick2line.set_markersize(15)
```

Result:

[image]